# svm with hard margin and C value

Tags: python, math, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have to create a a svm classifier with RBF kernel and a hard margin. If I undertood correctly, the kind of margin is controlled by the C-parameter. That is, the larger C parameter, the more hard margin I will be getting. Is there a typical C value that emulates a very robust "hard margin"? Or is there any other way to emulate a robust hardmargin?  Of course we could always discuss why do we need to emulate a hard margin. But in this case I need to emulate it!

```
clf = svm.SVC(C = ??,kernel="rbf",gamma =1.5,shrinking=False,cache_size=3000)
```

Comment: You could try setting it to some absurdly large value like `C=10e20`; I'm not sure how high you can set `C` without running into overflows, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you don't need that large values, but in general that is the idea. Just try setting it to 1e10 and then look at the resulting alphas.

If none of the alphas is at the C value, no regularization was applied (i.e. all points are classified correctly in the trainingset = hard margin).

Btw, if your dataset if very noisy and can not be separated with the kernel you are using, you can not achieve a hard margin.

Comment: Thanks Andreas! I have a question about getting the alphas, if I am using SVC, there are no methods to get the alphas and the actual support vectors. We have to read the "internal" parameters support_,support_vector_. Is it correct? Why there are no methods??

Comment: There are no methods because the alphas are stored in an attribute, ``dual_coef_``, see [the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC). The ``support_`` and ``support_vector_`` are explicitly documented and exposed to the user. The trailing underscore is a scikit-learn convention that says that these attributes are estimated from the data.